# Show length of filtered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

For the further use of my function it is necessary to know the length of the filtered array. Up until know I've written this to test the basic functionality:

```
function isInGraph(jnode){
    java.alert(jnode.name);
}
var difference = json.nodes.filter(isInGraph);
java.alert(JSON.stringify(difference));
```

`java.alert()` is a custom method that prints in the console. As expected it prints the name `name property` of every element in `json.nodes` exactly once. 
But how can I determinate the length of `json.nodes` within `isInGraph`? I tried to use the extra argument the `filter` function provides `arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])` as found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var difference = json.nodes.filter(isInGraph, json.length);
function isInGraph(jnode){
    java.alert(jnode.name);
    java.alert(Number(this));
}
```

The above code only prints `NaN`. How can I use the `json.nodes.length` in my `isInGraph` function?

Structure:

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {...},
        {...}
     ],
     "links":[
        {...},
        {...}
     ]
}
```

Pretty standart for a d3 graph.

Comment: please add the structure or data of `json`.

Comment: Knowing that `difference` is the filtered array, can't you `difference.length` ?

Comment: I'm not yet interested in the difference, I want to know the size of the orignial filtered array

Comment: @Pikrass yep, this is what I want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can't but you can make some workaround to achieve this.

You should add additional parameter to `isInGraph` function and pass it in another one anonymous function

```
function isInGraph(jnode, arrayLength){
    java.alert(jnode.name);
}
var len = json.nodes.length;
var difference = json.nodes.filter(function(el) { return isInGraph(el, len); });
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `filter` is the object that will be set as `this` inside your callback. You can effectively use it to pass information:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function isInGraph(node) {
    // this.len contains the length
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("len: "+this.len+" "));
    return true;
}

array.filter(isInGraph, {len: array.length});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vqa1th9m/